# Adding an extra artboard in the middle of a bunch of other artboards

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

I have a series of 23 artboards all designed and completed. i want to add a new page after page 3(artboard 3) but I don't want to add a new artboard in the end and then move all artworks one by one which is extremely time consuming. I want to add one artboard in the middle and maintain the sequence and order of artboards.
please help. Thank you! :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "in the middle"? Do you just mean the order of the artboards?

Comment: or do you mean Layers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Illustrator: how to change the artboard number?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50779/illustrator-how-to-change-the-artboard-number)

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/130429/add-an-artboard-between-two-specific-artboards-in-adobe-illustrator

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. What you do is you delete or add you artboards normally. Then rearange the artboards in artboards panel so that they are in the order you like the way they ought to be. Now the pages are in that order.

You might want to have the bards arranged nicely too. If so then run:

- **Object → Arboards → Rearrange...**.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you mean, but if you select the "Artboard" tool (Shift-O) you can create new artboards and move around or resize existing artboards.

To create a new artboard in the middle of an existing artboard (rather than moving it, which is what happens when you click and drag starting on an artboard), press "shift" before you start the click and drag.

"Shift" will also constrain the proportions of the new artboard you create.  So just release the "shift" key after you click and start dragging to get an artboard of any arbitrary proportions.